# MSBuildCommunityTasks folder missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, msbuildcommunitytasks

New Admin of a asp.net C# web solution

When I go to run msbuild against the project I get an error:

```
 error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Target
s" was not found. Also, tried to find "MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" in the fallback search pa
th(s) for $(MSBuildExtensionsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program F
iles (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the <I
mport> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths.
```

Project files first three lines of code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Package" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />
```

I'm running MS Community 2017.  I read MSBuild was included as part of the install.  Im not having much luck understanding what this is; is community tasks different than msbuild; does it not come with it and do i need to download it seperate of msbuild that comes installed with VS2017

Any help is greatly appreciated -

Thx,

boyd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSBuild Community Tasks is a separate setup: https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks